# Is there a way to have variable sized int and unsigned integer types in Rust?

Tags: math, rust, integer, fpga

In Rust, standard  integer type are sized [8, 16, 32, 64, 128 bits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-types).
But is it possible to manipulate integer types with a non-standard size like `u24`, `i7`, ... ?

These non-standard sizes can be useful for FPGA algorithm simulation.

Comment: This is not built in or supported in std, though I assume there are crates like [deranged](https://docs.rs/deranged/latest/deranged/index.html) which provide *some* measure of that.

Comment: [`bnum`](https://crates.io/crates/bnum) looks like it might cover this use case.

Comment: @user4815162342 `bnum` only seems to cover power of 2 byte integers larger than what's provided by default (`U256`, `U512`, …), not arbitrary bit wide ones like OP asks for.

Comment: @cafce25 Hmm. It's a bit better than that, e.g. `BIntD8<3>` gives you a 24-bit integer, and things like `U256` and `U512` are just aliases. But it's true that you can't get things like 7-bit integers - a byte is the lowest supported granularity,

Comment: There's always bit masking? 24 bit ints are 32 bit ints masked by 0xFFFFFF, 7 bit ints are 8 bit ints masked by 0x7F.

Answer (score 4):

Rust does not natively support arbitrary-sized integer types like `u24` or `i7` as part of its standard library. However, you can simulate such types using existing integer types and careful operations to ensure that only the relevant bits are used. For example, you can use a `u32` to represent a `u24` by ensuring that only the lower 24 bits are ever used.

Here's an example of how you might define and use a `u24` type in Rust:

```rust
struct U24(u32);

impl U24 {
    fn new(value: u32) -> Self {
        U24(value & 0x00FF_FFFF)
    }

    fn get(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0
    }

    // Add other methods as needed, ensuring that you mask the upper bits as appropriate.
}

fn main() {
    let a = U24::new(0x123456);
    let b = U24::new(0x654321);

    // Example operation: addition
    let sum = U24::new(a.get() + b.get());
    println!("Sum: {:X}", sum.get());
}
```

For complex or performance-critical applications, you might want to look into crates like `bitvec` which allows for more direct control over individual bits and can be used to simulate arbitrary bit-length integers.

Try the code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b65e61063b2d0f92e136b2228e9bfa29)